# estimator for standard error

Tags: standard-error, estimators, unbiased-estimator

I have searched extensively and I fail to find an answer. If you are not confident, please don't answer or modify the question, since it will confuse readers even more.

### Agree on some definitions

- Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a population
- A statistic is a function of $X_1, ..., X_n$
- Any statistic can be an estimator (not every statistic is a good estimator though)
- Sample mean $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a statistic and it follows a distribution. The standard error of sample mean is the standard deviation of its distribution

### Problem Setup

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a population with density $f$ with population mean $\mu$ and population standard deviation $\sigma$.

Let $\bar{X}$ be the sample mean. Let's say $\bar{X}$ follows a distribution with density $g$, mean $\mu_g$ and standard deviation $\sigma_g$. Although we don't know $g$, we know the $\mu_g = \mu$ and $\sigma_g = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. By the definition, the standard error of sample mean is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

If $\sigma$ is known, problem solved, great!

### Problem Description

However, if $\sigma$ is not known, people use either $\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$ or $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $S$ and $s$ are the unbiased sample standard deviation; with $S$ being estimator and $s$ being estimate.

Here is my question:

1. how do I even formulate an estimator for $\sigma_g$? Recall an estimator needs to be a statistic, which needs to be a function of a random sample. In this case, it only makes sense to think as follows: let $(\bar{X})_1, ..., (\bar{X})_m$ be a random sample of size $m$ where each $(\bar{X})_i$ follows density $g$ and construct a function of them. But no one does it, why?
2. why is $\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$ even an estimator for $\sigma_g$? Continuing with above thoughts in (1): let $\bar{X}$ be a random sample of size 1. However, $\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not even a function of $\bar{X}$. How is this OK?
3. Is $\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$ an unbiased estimator for $\sigma_g$? One simple way to show was $\mathbb{E}[\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}] = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \sigma_g$. I don't think it's correct since the expectation is taken with respect to $((\bar{X})_1, ..., (\bar{X})_m)$, not $(X_1, ..., X_n)$. Could anyone show the mathematics FORMALLY (e.g., using the above definitions and problem setup) on why or why not $\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$ an unbiased estimator for $\sigma_g$?

Comment: I believe (3) is fully addressed in other threads.  The key is that because $E[S^2]=\sigma_g^2,$ Jensen's Inequality implies $E[S] \ne \sigma_g.$  (2) is specious because all you have to do is stipulate that $S$ applies only when $n\gt 1.$ The remaining question (1) is mystifying, because $S$ already is an estimator of $\sigma_g$ according to your (correct) definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's the case that $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma_{g}$. The reason for this is that $s$ is not an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$.

One thing I'm not understanding from what you've said, is the difference between S and s. You say that S is the unbiased sample standard deviation and s is its estimate, but how are these different things? I would have though that

$$s= \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}{N-1}}$$

and this is an estimator, defined wrt your sample. There is no S, some true value/latent parameter you're trying to estimate.

That aside though, the above s is not an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$. If you didn't take the square root, then you have an unbiased estimator for $\sigma ^{2}$, but that does not mean its square root is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$. In fact, to quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) directly,

> It is not possible to find an estimate of the standard deviation which is unbiased for all population distributions, as the bias depends on the particular distribution. Much of the following relates to estimation assuming a normal distribution.

That aside though, I feel your question was getting at something else, but I'm not quite getting it (perhaps related to the S vs s confusion?).

If we ignored this issue that the square root of the unbiased estimator of the variance is not an unbiased estimator of the standard deviation, is this not all pretty straightforward?

You want an unbiased estimator for $\sigma_{g}$. In words, if you take a sample of size n, that sample will have a standard deviation. You could take infinite such samples, each would have a variance, and then you could take the average of those variances, you want to estimate what that value would be, from a single sample of size n.

You also know from basic probability that if you knew $\sigma$, then it's easy, $\sigma_{g}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. So isn't it fairly straightforward to say that if you have an unbiased estimator $\hat{\sigma}$ for $\sigma$, then $\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}$ will be an unbiased estimator for $\sigma_{g}?$

From there, we're back at the point that technically, the estimator s above is not an unbiased estimator for $\sigma$, but [it's pretty close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation#/media/File:Stddevc4factor.jpg), and thus dividing s by $\sqrt{n}$ is going to be a pretty good estimator for $\sigma_{g}.$

Appreciate this isn't a proof, more of a going through the logical steps one by one. Does this make sense or is there a particular step here you disagree with ?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that in some ways, the premise of some of your question itself is flawed, at least from the perspective of what the typical goal of a statistical analysis is. Specifically, much of your confusion seems to stem from the fact that you are assuming that $S/\sqrt n$ is meant as an estimator of $\sigma_g$. However, this is not really the main goal of most statistical analyses I am aware of.

Typically in the sort of setting you are describing, our primary interest in performing statistical inference is to try to understand the average of $X$ in the population $f$, given formally by $\mu=\mathbb E_f[X]$. This objective really consists of two subgoals:

**Subgoal 1:** We would like to have a good estimate of $\mu$.

**Subgoal 2:** We would like to have a way of quantifying how uncertain we are about $\mu$, even after seeing the data. I will be taking for granted in what follows that this will be your goal in analyzing data as well.

Given this objective, we draw a sample of $X$ values $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$, which in the most ideal case, we model as i.i.d. and coming from the underlying population distribution $f$. I assume that this i.i.d. model of sampling is what you have in mind when you describe $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ as a "random sample".

Given this setup, the most standard way to proceed is the following procedure:

1. Construct sample mean $\bar X_n = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$
2. Construct sample standard deviation  $\hat s_n \equiv \sqrt{\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X_n)^2}$
3. Find standard error, $se_n\equiv \hat s_n/\sqrt{n}$.
4. Construct (say) 95% confidence intervals, $[\bar X_n-2se_n,\bar X+2se_n]$

Why does this procedure make sense? Let us discuss each in turn. First of all, consider $\bar X_n$. The justification for using $\bar X_n$ is that as you mentioned, given our assumptions $\bar X_n$ is an *unbiased* estimate of $\mu$ in that $\mathbb E[X_n]=\mu$. Perhaps more importantly, the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) implies that $\bar X_n$ is also a *consistent estimator* of $\mu$ in that $\bar X_n\overset p\to \mu$ as $n\to\infty$. Roughly, this means that provided we collect large enough of a sample, we can make sure that $\bar X_n$ is "sufficiently close" to $\mu$ with "sufficiently high probability". If we only cared about subgoal 1, then we could stop here.

The fact that we care about subgoal 2 justifies why we even care about estimating $\sigma$ and pursuing this second goal is where steps 2-4 of the above procedure come in. These steps break uncertainty quantification into a series of more digestable sub-parts. The main intuition for these steps is that there are two conceptually distinct reasons why $\bar X_n$ might not, for a fixed sample size $n$ be very close to $\mu$. First, it could be that each individual observation $X_i$ is not likely to be very close to its mean value, $\mu$, so each individual observation does not give us much information by itself about $\mu$. Second, it could be that $n$ is not very high, so we need to collect more data.

The computation of $\hat s_n$ helps us to quantify the first reason why $\bar X_n$ may not be very close to $\mu$. Specifically, rearranging the expression for $\hat s_n$, we find that
$$\hat s_n = \sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bar X_n^2\right)}$$
Applying the law of large numbers and the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) imply that
$$\hat s_n\overset p\to \sqrt{\mathbb E_f[X^2]-\mathbb E_f[X]^2}=\mathrm{sd}_f(X)\equiv\sigma$$
where $\mathrm{sd}_f(X)$ is the population standard deviation of $X$. Thus, $\hat s_n$ gives us a consistent estimate of how close $X_i$ is likely to be to its mean.

Steps 3+4 then incorporate information about how big the sample is, and how sample size affects uncertainty about $\mu$. First, looking at step 3, this is the step that I suspect your confusion stems from. It would *seem* from the logical flow of what we have been doing so far that the standard error $se_n$ is an estimator of something, and in particular, based on your question, I presume that it looks to you like it should be an estimator of $\mathrm{sd}_g(\bar X_n)$. However, the **key point** I hope to convey here is that in constructing our standard errors, we are doing something **related** but **subtly different**.

Specifically, to understand why constructing standard errors is important, it is actually helpful to view steps 3+4 together rather than looking at step 3 in isolation. The justification for these steps taken together comes from the following derivation:

First, by the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem),
$$\sqrt n\sigma^{-1}(\bar X_n-\mu)\overset d\to\mathcal N(0,1)$$
where $\overset d\to$ denotes convergence in distribution and throughout, I take the $-1$ superscript to denote taking a reciprocal. This tells us roughly that the random variable, $\sqrt n\sigma^{-1}(\bar X_n-\mu)$ formed by appropriately shifting and scaling $\bar X_n$ will behave increasingly like a standard Normal random variable when sample sizes are large. As you noted, this formula is not useful directly because $\sigma$ may not directly be known. However, because of the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), and because in our discussion of step 2, we noted that $\hat s_n\overset p\to\sigma$, the following modified central limit theorem where we replace $\sigma$ with $\hat s_n$ also holds:
$$\sqrt n\hat s_n^{-1}(\bar X_n-\mu)\overset d\to\mathcal N(0,1)$$

How do we use this result? One way is to ask what guesses $\tilde \mu$ of the true value of $\mu$ are "plausible" given the data. The usual statistical significance framework defines "plausible" in the following way: in light of the central limit theorem, if $\mu=\tilde\mu$, then we would expect that the random variable $\sqrt n\hat s_n^{-1}(\bar X_n-\tilde\mu)$ follows a $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distribution. If it did follow such a distribution, then the probability that it takes on "extreme" values is $\mathrm{Pr}[|\sqrt n\hat s_n^{-1}(\bar X_n-\tilde\mu)|\geq 2]\approx 1 - \Phi(2) - \Phi(-2)\approx 0.05$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal. Thus, guesses $\tilde \mu$ such that $|\sqrt n\hat s_n^{-1}(\bar X_n-\tilde\mu)|\geq 2$ are ruled to be "implausible" on the grounds that for the trule value of $\mu$, we would only expect to see such an "extreme" value of $|\sqrt n\hat s_n^{-1}(\bar X_n-\tilde\mu)|$ 5% of the time, which is pretty unlikely. We call the 95% confidence interval the set of $\tilde \mu$ values which *are* plausible $|\sqrt n\hat s_n^{-1}(\bar X_n-\tilde\mu)|\leq 2$.

Rearranging this last inequality gives us that our 95% confidence interval should indeed be the form described in step 4
$$\left[\bar X_n-2\frac{\hat s_n}{\sqrt n},\bar X_n+2\frac{\hat s_n}{\sqrt n}\right] = \left[\bar X_n-2se_n,\bar X_n+2se_n\right]$$

Summarizing, the importance of the standard error is **not** that $\sigma_g$ is directly a parameter of interest. Rather, when we are clear about the problem we are trying to solve (quantifying uncertainty about $\mu$ given our data), we derive *as a consequence of this underlying question* that the quantity $se_n=\hat s_n/\sqrt n$ happens to be a part of the solution. It just happens to be the case that $se_n$ superficially *looks like* an estimate of $\sigma_g$.